# QDialog or QMessageBox show Qt::BusyCursor when added to existing application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am new to qt and I have an issue I cannot understand.
I have created my own QDialog and now I want to add it to an existing application.

In QT creator, everything works fine but when I add either my custom dialogue or even a 
message box to the existing code, something odd happens.

The dialogue works just fine but when I hover over the main area of the dialogue
the icon changes to a Qt::BusyCursor the busy wait icon.

At first I assumed this must be a threading issue but then isn't .exec() suppose to block?
Also when I hover over the title bar or the message box / dialogue, it seems fine i.e it shows a Qt::ArrowCursor, in both cases the dialogue functionally works fine also.

I have tried to set the .setCursor() on both and it did not work still a busy icon.

can anyone give me some hints as to what I might look at to investigate this more.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: add your code Please. How do you create dialog, set cursor, which code this dialog contains etc.

Comment: I don't have permission to redistribute the code. I understand what I am asking is very difficult, I am hoping people might recall something similar but I cannot release the code.

Comment: I don't know if this helps at all but this is how I do the messagebox.
    QMessageBox msg;
    msg.setText("Test");
    msg.setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    msg.exec();

Comment: So I think that this code can contains a lot of interesting things that can cause this(if it is sinple, then you can add this). In this case I blind, so I can sugestie you to use     QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor)); and
    QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();. Look what happens. It can be a solution, but it is not so good

Comment: I can see what your suggestion is doing. I was hoping to see if there is some rule about calling message box that can cause this.

Comment: your messageBox calling is normal, but I don't understand: does `QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));` solve problem?

Comment: Hi Chernobyl, yes it does work, I add the override in the constructor of my QDialog subclass and undo the override in the destructor and the dialog displays correctly throughout. This is great because I should be able to debug it now and see why it is required. It also helps to confirm there is no threading issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to use

`QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));`

and reset it with

```
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();.
```